# Investigative charges

Tags: criminal-law, legal-terms

I had some charges against me in 2015. One is *nolle prosse* and the other says investigative charges. What does this mean?

From my understanding *nolle prosse* means the charges were dropped is that correct? My case status says closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Nolle presse* means that the prosecutor has dropped the charges, and depending upon the jurisdiction, either bars the prosecutor from bringing them again and at least states that the prosecutor does not intend to bring the charges again.

"Investigative charges" is a little hard to evaluate out of context. It could mean that those charges are still under investigation and while they have been dropped for the time being could be refiled, unlike the nolle presse charged; or it could mean that those charges were only brought in connection with the investigation, in which case they are mooted by the dismissal of the primary charges. I suspect that the former is true. In that case, the nolle presse charges will not be brought against you in the future, but the prosecutor reserves the right to bring the other charges in the future if more evidence is developed (at least until the statute of limitations, if any, runs on those charges).

But, either way, the status quo is that you do not have criminal charges actively pending against you in court.

Comment: Does it also mean the battery is seen as a conviction?

Comment: Neither *nolle presse* or *investigative charges* would be convictions.